# symfony 1.4 adding a BCC recipient to mailer

Tags: symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I know with swift directly you can create a Recipient_List and do ->addBcc() . How would i do this same thing in the context of symfony 1.4

```
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose();
$message->setSubject(sfConfig::get('app_email_welcome_subject'));
$message->setTo($user->getUsername());
$message->setFrom(sfConfig::get('app_email_from'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

compose() return a Swift_Message object, you can use setBcc() or addBcc() methods as you would with swift

Answer (score 0):

if you use symfony 1.4 .your code can set

```
         $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
         $message->setSubject($subject);
         $message->setFrom($from);
         $message->setBody($body);

         $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(sfConfig::get('app_email_host'), sfConfig::get('app_email_port'), 'ssl')
            ->setUsername(sfConfig::get('app_email_username'))
            ->setPassword(sfConfig::get('app_email_password'));
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

when use it can send email use gmail....

i think you can!

example: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html